# amazon sqs only get messages with a specific message attribute and value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm building a bunch of systems where they will communicate with each other via SQS.  The issue I am having is that messages that are just for all message are getting read instead of the ones just for that service, so now I have messages for different services in flight an inaccessible to the proper destination.  Any idea how I can use the MEssageAttributes of a message to only retrieve messages with a particular destination identified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you basically cannot do that with SQS.
you can either create separate queues per service or you can look at possibly using something else (rabbit mq, etc).